# Array of Pointers to Structs referencing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm writing a "nano social network", just by registering a member and connecting them using pointers in a structure. I'm trying to use a connect function in which I'm not sure I'm writing it in a correct way because the program crashes when I try to run it and I get 0 errors and 0 warnings (warnings at high level using CodeBlocks).

First I register at least 2 members and then when I try to connect them via the connect() function I get that the user I wish to connect with does not exist which is part of the condition in the function. Is it that the users I'm registering don't get saved in the memory? Or am I writing something wrong?

The connect function can be simplified by all means but I will do that once I'm clear with my mistakes.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct member{
    int num;
    char name[10];
    struct member *m1;
    struct member *m2;
    struct member *m3;
    struct member *m4;
    struct member *m5;
}*ptr[5];

void addmember(){
    int i;

    printf("Enter new members details:\n");
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct member));
        printf("\n Enter ID number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &ptr[i]->num);
        printf("\n Enter Name:\n");
        scanf("%s", ptr[i]->name);
    }

    printf("\n Added member details are:");
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("\n ID number : %d", ptr[i]->num);
        printf("\nName : %s", ptr[i]->name);
        }
}
void connect(){ //when always typing the first username
    int i=0;
    printf("Please type in your user name : \n");
    scanf("%s", ptr[i]->name);

    if(ptr[i]->name == ptr[0]->name){ //being first user connecting.
        printf("Please type existing member name you wish to connect with :\n");
        scanf("%s", ptr[i]->name);

        if(ptr[i]->name == ptr[1]->name){
            ptr[0]->m1 = ptr[1]->m1;
            ptr[1]->m2 = ptr[0]->m2;
            printf("member 1 connected with member 2!\n");
        }
        else if(ptr[i]->name == ptr[2]->name){
            ptr[0]->m1 = ptr[2]->m1;
            ptr[2]->m3 = ptr[0]->m3;
            printf("member 1 connected with member 3!\n");
        }
        else if(ptr[i]->name == ptr[3]->name){
            ptr[0]->m1 = ptr[3]->m1;
            ptr[3]->m4 = ptr[0]->m4;
            printf("member 1 connected with member 4!\n");
        }
        else if(ptr[i]->name == ptr[4]->name){
            ptr[0]->m1 = ptr[4]->m1;
            ptr[4]->m5 = ptr[0]->m5;
            printf("member 1 connected with member 5!\n");
        }
         else{
            printf("User you typed in does not exist\n");
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    int op = 0;

    printf("Welcome to NSN, please register 4 members to proceed to options menu.\n");
    addmember(); //adding 4 members

    //general member section
    printf("Now please select an option by typing option number\n");
    while(op != 3){
        printf("\n");
        printf("1. Add new member.\n 2. Connect with member.\n 3. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice:\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch(op){
        case 1:
             addmember();
            break;
        case 2:
            connect();
            break;
        case 3:
             printf("Bye!\n");
            exit(0);
             break;
         default:
             printf("Invalid choice!\n");
         }
    }
    return(0);
 }
```

As stated before when I use the connect function after having registered at least 3 members and typing an existing name I always get the answer "User you typed in does not exist", is this somehow that I'm not saving this in memory or am I missing a function?

Comment: @Gernot1976 will do.

Comment: @Gernot1976 I think you had to highlight **Minimal**.

Comment: The `connect` function starts by overwriting `ptr[0]->name` with the name you just entered, and then compares it with itself...

Comment: You should use length checks with `%s` to avoid buffer overflows, e.g. `scanf("%9s", ptr[i]->name);`

Comment: When you malloc your structs, you leave `m1` through `m5` uninitialized so later on your code will be accessing through wild pointers. suggest to initialize them to NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare `char` arrays like this, you're comparing addresses these pointers point to:

```
ptr[i]->name == ptr[0]->name
```

You have to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function:

```
strcmp(ptr[i]->name, ptr[0]->name)
```

And also, think about your `connect` function - why is it using the first `member` for input - `scanf("%s", ptr[i]->name);`? You rather want to type in member **A** and **B**'s names, find their positions in `ptr` array, then connect them.

I also don't get why you have these five pointers to `member` in `member` itself. You already have an array.

Comment: I think that is what i was doing in connect but had to make it shorter to post it here, so the example is only for the first member case. Or you mean another thing?

Comment: And it's already too long. Learn how to use loops, also added a bit to my answer.

Comment: "You rather want to type in member A and B names, find their positions in ptr array, then connect them." - I told you everything in this sentence.

Comment: yes i was confusing the thing with the pointers, i will fix the function length with loops. Your answer was all i needed to understand this thanks.